# Unable to overwrite class method in pyqt6 application

Tags: python, class, methods, pyqt, pyqt6

So normally you can overwrite a class method by doing something like this.

```
class A():
    def test(self):
        return 1+1

def edit_patch(func):
    def inner(*args,**kwargs):
        print('this test worked')
    return inner

a=A()
a.test = edit_patch(a.test)
```

Now `a.test` will return `'this test worked'` instead of `2`. I'm trying to do something similar in my pyqt6 application. The function below belongs to the "main" class in my code and is connected to a button click. This function is meant to instantiate another class (which is another window in pyqt6). That part works, but I would like to alter the behavior of the `select` function in this instance. However the method above doesn't seem to work as the select function continues to exhibit the default behavior.

```
def edit_proj(self):
        self.psearch=PSearch(conn=self.conn,parent=self)
        self.psearch.select = edit_patch(self.psearch.select)
        self.psearch.show()
```

Any help on this would be great

As requested, here is an MRE

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

def edit_patch(func):
    def inner(*args,**kwargs):
        print('this test worked')
    return inner

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(50, 50)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.EditProjButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.EditProjButton.setObjectName("EditProjButton")

        self.EditProjButton.clicked.connect(self.nextwindow)

    def nextwindow(self):
        print('hello from main window')
        self.newwindow=Ui_ProjSearchForm(QtWidgets.QWidget())

        self.newwindow.select = edit_patch(self.newwindow.select)

        self.newwindow.show()

class Ui_ProjSearchForm(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.SearchButton.clicked.connect(self.select)

    def setupUi(self, ProjSearchForm):
        ProjSearchForm.setObjectName("ProjSearchForm")
        ProjSearchForm.resize(100, 100)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(ProjSearchForm)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.SearchButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(ProjSearchForm)
        self.SearchButton.setObjectName("SearchButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.SearchButton, 0, 2, 1, 1)


    def select(self):
        print('this is default behavior')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: First of all, be aware that not all functions can be overwritten. In python bindings that wrap C++ libraries, only *virtual* functions can be overridden. Unfortunately, your example is too abstract to understand what is actually going on, and we know absolutely nothing about the "main" class in which you call `edit_proj` nor `PSearch`, so I suggest you to provide a [mre].

Comment: There's too much code to post all of it. If there's something specific you would like to see I can post that.

Comment: Also `select` is just a function i defined in that class

Comment: I asked to post a MRE, not all your code. Right now it's impossible to answer, because your code is insufficient to understand where is the issue.

Comment: @musicamante ok MRE posted. The button in the new window still prints `this is default behavior` instead of the the `this test worked`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signal connections work by passing a *reference* to a callable, and that reference is an "internal" pointer to that function. Overwriting the *name* of that function will have absolutely no result.

Take this example:

```py
class Test(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Click me!')
        self.clicked.connect(self.doSomething)
        self.doSomething = lambda: print('bye!')

    def doSomething(self):
        print('hello!')
```

The code above will always print "hello!", because you passed the reference to the instance method `doSomething` that existed at the time of the connection; overwriting it will not change the result.

If you need to create a connection that can be overwritten, you have different possibilities.

### Pass the function to the constructor

You can set the function as an optional argument in the `__init__` and then connect it if specified, otherwise use the default behavior:

```
    def nextwindow(self):
        self.newwindow = Ui_ProjSearchForm(edit_patch(self.newwindow.select))

class Ui_ProjSearchForm(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, func=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        if func is not None:
            self.SearchButton.clicked.connect(func)
        else:
            self.SearchButton.clicked.connect(self.select)
```

### Create a method for the connection

In this case we pass the reference to a specific method that will create the connection, eventually *disconnecting* any previous connection (remember that signals can be connected to multiple functions, and even the same function multiple times). This is similar to the approach above.

```py
    def nextwindow(self):
        self.newwindow = Ui_ProjSearchForm()
        self.newwindow.setSelectFunc(edit_patch(self.newwindow.select))

class Ui_ProjSearchForm(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, func=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.SearchButton.clicked.connect(self.select)

    def select(self):
        print('this is default behavior')

    def setSelectFunc(self, func):
        try:
            self.SearchButton.clicked.disconnect(self.select)
        except TypeError:
            pass
        self.select = func
        self.SearchButton.clicked.connect(self.select)
```

### Use a lambda

As said above, the problem was in trying to overwrite the function that was connected to the signal: even if the connected function is a wrapper, the direct reference for the connection is not actually overwritten.

If you, instead, connect to a lambda that finally calls the instance method, it will work as expected, because the lambda is dynamically computed at the time of its execution and at that time `self.select` will be a reference to the overwritten function.

```py
    def nextwindow(self):
        self.newwindow = Ui_ProjSearchForm()
        self.newwindow.select = edit_patch(self.newwindow.select)

class Ui_ProjSearchForm(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, func=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.SearchButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.select())

    def select(self):
        print('this is default behavior')
```

Some unrelated but still important notes:

1. You should never edit pyuic generated files, nor try to merge their code into your script or mimic their behavior. Instead, follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).
2. Passing a new QWidget instance as argument is pointless (other than wrong and potentially dangerous); if you want to create a new window for the new widget, just avoid any parent at all, otherwise use QDialog for modal windows.
3. Only classes and constants should have capitalized names, everything else should be named starting with lowercase letters (this includes object names created in Designer); read more about this and other important topics in the official [Style Guide for Python Code](//python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008).

Comment: i ended up going with the ol' unplug it and plug it back in method, though i didn't bother to write another function for it. The lambda idea you came up with is clever.

Comment: @SuperStew Remember that `obj.disconnect()` always raises a TypeError if the signal is not connected to anything and, most importantly, always disconnects from ***any*** previously connected slot. Unless you really know what you're doing (and you have absolute control and knowledge of what's happening), doing it is normally discouraged, as some Qt objects automatically connect to internal slots for their default behavior, so you might face unexpected behavior in some (relatively rare, but not irrelevant) cases.

Comment: Well i don't know what i'm doing, but i have pretty good control over it. If i find it causing issues down the line, i'll throw a lambda in there

Comment: Be aware that lambdas might be tricky, especially if you need to use arguments. The first two methods I suggested are actually better, especially because you can also call them internally from the class. Unfortunately, while your MRE improved your question, we still don't really know why you need to override the `select` method with an external function: for all we know, this whole approach might be wrong, as it was done under wrong assumptions, and proper usage of signals could've sufficed.

Comment: I needed to override `select` because I wanted the same class/ui button that I had already defined to function slightly differently when called from the main window.

Comment: Sorry but it was already clear that you wanted a different behavior, and that is not a sufficient explanation. For instance, is that different behavior changed *dynamically* (for instance, based on dynamically created prerequisites)? Or is it just a "convenience" overrride for special cases (for which a further subclass would suffice)? There are dozens of possible approaches, but until you provide a more detailed description about your needs, it's really impossible to actually help you in the proper way. In fact, we may be suggesting a *wrong* answer, because you asked the wrong question.

Comment: It's probably the convenience one. Sure another subclass could have worked, but I figure "less code = more good". I'm not sure how to give more details without explaining all the specifics of the app

Comment: "less code" is fine, unless it becomes "not enough code" or its explanation is too abstract, or provides the "wrong" details (making it an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). You don't need to explain all the specifics of the app, but find a way to explain the *concept* as simple (but still detailed) *and* clear as possible.

Comment: OK here it goes. The class/window that contains the `select` function is normally used for searching a db, and appending the selected entry to the data set of the parent class/window, which is then displayed for the user to interact with. (Note using "parent" loosely as there's not any inheritance going on, parent just calls "child"). I needed to add a function that could perform the same search, but then allow for the user to select and edit the db entry, there was no need to append data to the parent dataset after the select, and there was no similar parent data set in this new scenario.

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, the function you're passing will perform a query to the database based on some aspects declared when you're calling the wrapper? That can be still achieved with signals, but it depends on how `select` is called and the whole behavior of the "child" class. Note that Qt has an SQL framework (QtSql) which has a very comprehensive API that makes it (usually) easy to work with databases and records, and you can even use proxy models to filter tables or results.

Comment: That's about right. QtSql would probably be the way to go if this was some enterprise level software, but at this point i can't see it being worth it to struggle through another QT framework when python can handle the sql stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I've figured out a solution (in the MRE posted in question). There's some shenanigans that go on in the back ground once you `connect` a button in the UI to a function. It's not a "live" connection like in the `a.test` example, so edits to the function later don't have an impact on how the button functions.

So, if we replace

```
self.newwindow.select = edit_patch(self.newwindow.select)
```

with

```
self.newwindow.SearchButton.clicked.disconnect()
self.newwindow.select = edit_patch(self.newwindow.select)
self.newwindow.SearchButton.clicked.connect(self.newwindow.select)
```

we suddenly get the desired behavoir from the button. This was entirely too frustrating.